# How to parse text and be forgiving of white space looking for specific functions or patterns in .NET?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, whitespace, dsl

I wanted to find out some best practice methods how to parse text blocks looking for function-like text and be forgiving of white space within the text without having to do something like configure and utilize ANTLR (or something similar) just for this one case.  The only thing that will be sought after in the parsing are variations on one particular item.

Example:  In the example below I'd like to find out what the value is for Text, Required, and Type if they are present.  They may not all be present.  In text blocks 1 and 2, I would want to know that the values on both items are the same when the interested values are parsed out.  Text is "What is the label text", that Required is true, and that Type is null or not specified while ignoring or forgiving all the spacing.

```
1. This is user entered text. {{Text="What is the label text {{ Ignore me and treat me as text }}?",Required=true              }}. I am some more user added {} text. 
2. This is user entered text. {{ Text     ="What is the label text {{ Ignore me and treat me as text }}?", Required=       True}}. I am some more user added {} text. 
3. This is user entered text. {{Text="What is the label text?",Type=Date}}. I am some more user added {} text. 
4. This is user entered text. {{ Text = "What is the label text?", Type = Date }}I am some more user added {} text. 
5. This is user entered text. {{ Text = "What is the label text?", Type = Date, Required = True }}I am some more user added {} text.
```

Comment: Why don't you use xml or json? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 0):

Since I see no nesting in your examples, regular expressions will do.

Comment: There could potentially be nesting for example, but I thought that may be a more complex sample to start off with, but it would help to know if this situation could be matched with "infinite" nesting, e.g. the Lookup function could have another Lookup function within it.  In this example the user's profile name would looked up, converted to upper and replaced within the text "What is the label {0}?" to become "What is the label ADONTZ?": This is user entered text. {{Text="What is the label text {{ Lookup = "Profile", Property="Name",    Format="ToUpper()"}}?",Required=true              }}.

Comment: Infinite nesting will require "adult" parser like CoCo/R, ANTLR, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of three regexes.

`Text\s*=\s*\"(?<Text>.*)\".*Type\s*=\s*(?<Type>\w*).*Required\s*=\s*(?<Required>\w*)` will match when all three parts are present.

`Text\s*=\s*\"(?<Text>.*)\".*Type\s*=\s*(?<Type>\w*)` will match when 'Required' is missing.

`Text\s*=\s*\"(?<Text>.*)\".*Required\s*=\s*(?<Required>\w*)` will match when 'Type' is missing.

Use can try these expressions out using this [online regex parser](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?i){{(?:[\s,]*(?:Text\s*=\s*""((?:[^""\\]|\\.)+)""|Type\s*=\s*(\w+)|Required\s*=\s*(\w+)))+");
foreach (Match m in re.Matches(text)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Text: {0}\nType: {1}\nRequired: {2}\n", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3]);
}
```

Text, Required and Type can be in any order and are optional.
This regex assumes that there can be escaped sequences inside Text.